# We say that $U \subset X$ is open if $U \setminus A$ is open in the standard topology of the plane. Is $X$ (a) Hausdorff, (b) separable, (c) connected

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = \Bbb R^2$ and $A \subset X$ be a line. We say that $U \subset X$ is open if $U \setminus A$ is open in the standard topology of the plane. Show that this forms a topology on $X$. Is the space (a) Hausdorff, (b) separable, (c) connected?

Denote the generated topology by $\tau$. We have that $\emptyset \setminus A = \emptyset$ so $\emptyset \in \tau$. Also in $\Bbb R^2$ the set $\Bbb R^2 \setminus A$ is open so $\Bbb R^2 \in \tau$.

Now let $U_i \in \tau$, then $\bigcup_{i} U_i$ is open if $\bigcup_{i} U_i \setminus A$ is open. we have that $$\bigcup_{i} U_i \setminus A = \bigcup_{i} (U_i \setminus A)$$ and if each of the $(U_i \setminus A)$ are open then the union is also?

If $U_i, U_j \in \tau$, then $U_i \cap U_j$ is open if $(U_i \cap U_j) \setminus A = (U_i \setminus A) \cap (U_j \setminus A)$ is open, but this is also open if $(U_i \setminus A)$ and $(U_j \setminus A)$ are open?

I'm confused if the question gives me the option to assume that $U \setminus A$ are open in the standard topology or am I to show this somehow?

For the Hausdorff property we have that $X$ is Hausdorff if the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x) \mid x \in \Bbb R \}$ is closed. This is the case in our situation since the complement $U \setminus \Delta$ is open for every $U \in \tau$?

The last two properties I don't know how to show. Aren't they mutually exclusive so it would satisfy to show either one of them?

Comment: To prove that $\tau$ is a topology of course you have to assume that the $U_i$ are open, that is the same as saying $U_i$ are elements of $\tau$, which means that $U_i\setminus A$ is open in the standard topology by definition.

Answer (score 2):

You have essentially proved that $\tau$ is a topology.It is Hausdorff because every open set in the usual topology is also open in $\tau$ and usual topology is Hausdorff.

It is separable because any open set contains points with rational coordinates.

It is not connected. Let $A$ be the points below the line and $B$ the points on and above the line. These are open in $\tau$ and their union is $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the line (fixed) be called $\ell$. It is known that $\ell$ is closed in the standard Euclidean topology $\tau_e$ on $\Bbb R^2$.

So if $U \in \tau_e$ then $U \setminus \ell = U \cap \ell^\complement \in \tau_e$ too so $U$ is in the defined topology $$\tau := \{O \subseteq \Bbb R^2\mid O \setminus \ell \in \tau_e\}$$

on $\Bbb R^2$. Your proof that it *is* a topology is fine and straightforward by properties of the set operations and the fact that $\tau_e$ already is a topology.

$\tau_e \subseteq \tau$ implies that $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff too: we can separate points in $\tau_e$ and use the same sets in $\tau$ too.

$\Bbb Q^2$ is dense in $(X,\tau_e)$ and still dense in $(X,\tau)$.

$\ell$ as a subspace of $(X,\tau)$ is clopen and discrete, so Jones' lemma implies that $(X,\tau)$ is not normal (and so not metrisable).

If $p \in \ell$, then $\{p\}$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$ and also open in $(X,\tau)$ so the space is not connected: there are lots of non-trivial clopens.